# Can I display an eclipse plugin/action based on a preference?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a eclipse plug-in, to be more precise I have an action which is triggered via the context menu of any folder. I do also have a Preferences page where I have a checkbox. I want to only display the action if that checkbox is enabled.

My plugin.xml:

```
<action
   class="com.something.MyClass"
   enablesFor="1"
   id="com.something.MyClass"
   label="Label
   menubarPath="path/group.smth">
   <enablement>
      <objectClass 
         name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
      </objectClass>
   </enablement>
</action>
```

So. Is there any possibility to display the action based on a specific preference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that using (deprecated) actions as the enablement expression is rather limited.

You can also use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to contribute to context menus. In this case you can use the `test` element to invoke a 'property tester' defined using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point. I don't think there are any predefined property testers for preferences but testers are not difficult to write.